# System.StringException: Invalid id: Test

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, visual-workflow

I am writing a testclas for a trigger of a flow but get the error: System.StringException: Invalid id: Test In my system debug I get an Id for my Pricebook so what am I missing?

Trigger:

```
trigger StartFlow on Order__c (after update ) 
{
    Set<Id> opptyIds = new Set<Id>();
    public Flow.Interview.Create_Renewal_OppLineItems_from_Invoice_record DummyFlow {get; set;}
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        for(Order__c o : Trigger.New) 
        {
            if((o.Opportunity_Name__c!=Null) && (o.Opportunity_Name__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).Opportunity_Name__c)){
            //if(o.Opportunity_Name__c!=Null){

            string value0 = o.Account_Name__r.Customer_Profile_Pricebook__c;
            date   value1 = o.End_Date__c;
            double value2 = o.Year_Enddate_1_day__c;
            string value3 = o.Journal_Reader_Code__c;
            double value4 = o.Number_of_Users__c;
            double value5 = o.Renewal_Number__c;
            Id     value6 = o.Opportunity_Name__c;
            Id     value7 = o.Product__c;
            string value8 = o.Delegate_Admin__c;
            string value9 = o.CurrencyIsoCode;

            Map<String, Object> myMap = new Map<String, Object>();
            myMap.put('VarCustomerProfile', value0);//Customer_Profile_Pricebook__c    
            myMap.put('VarInvoiceEnddate', value1);  //End_Date__c
            myMap.put('VarInvoiceEnddateYear', value2);  //Year_Enddate_1_day__c
            myMap.put('VarInvoiceJRC', value3); //Journal_Reader_Code__c
            myMap.put('VarInvoiceNumberOfUsers', value4); //Number_of_Users__c
            myMap.put('VarInvoiceRenewalNumber', value5);//Renewal_Number__c
            myMap.put('VarOppId', value6);//OpportinityID
            myMap.put('VarProductId', value7);//ProductId
            myMap.put('VarDelegateAdmin', value8);//Delegate_Admin__c
            myMap.put('VarInvoiceCurIsoCode', value9);//CurrencyIsoCode

            DummyFlow = new Flow.Interview.Create_Renewal_OppLineItems_from_Invoice_record(myMap);
            DummyFlow.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Testclass:

```
@istest
public class StartFlowTestClass {
    @istest 
    private static void StartFlowTestClass(){

        Product2 prod = new Product2(Name = 'Laptop X200', 
        Family = 'Hardware');
        insert prod;

        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

        PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = pricebookId, Product2Id = prod.Id,
            UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true);
        insert standardPrice;

        Pricebook2 customPB = new Pricebook2(Name='Custom Pricebook', isActive=true);
        insert customPB;

        PricebookEntry customPrice = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = customPB.Id, Product2Id = prod.Id,
            UnitPrice = 12000, IsActive = true);
        insert customPrice;

        Account acct = new Account ( Name='Testaccount',Customer_Profile__c='Wo',Billingstreet='Palmboomstraat 23', BillingCountry='Netherlands',BillingPostalcode='3500AA', BillingCity='Utrecht',IsBillingAddress__c=true,
        Shippingstreet='Palmboomstraat 23', ShippingCountry='Netherlands',ShippingPostalcode='3500AA', ShippingCity='Utrecht');
        insert acct;
        system.debug('acct.Id '+acct.Id);
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name = 'TestOpp', Type='Renewal',AccountId=acct.Id, StageName='DMU check',CloseDate= System.today().addMonths(1),Pricebook2Id=customPB.Id);
        insert opp;
        system.debug('opp.Pricebook2Id '+opp.Pricebook2Id);
        Contact cont = new Contact(Lastname='Test', Initials__c='A.A.', AccountId=acct.Id, Email='testcontact@test.nl', Title='Consultant' , Department='Academic');
        insert cont;
        Order__c ord = new Order__c(Account_Name__c=acct.Id, Delegate_Admin__c=cont.LastName, Number_of_Users__c=5,  CurrencyIsoCode='EUR - Euro',Order_Amount__c=1500,Opportunity_Name__c=Opp.Name);
        insert ord;

        Test.startTest();
        ord.OppLineItemId__c=opp.Id; 
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(opp.OpportunityLineItems.size(),1);   
    }
}
```

Comment: From the answers you've gotten so far (and the comments on them), it appears that you're getting a different error message than the one you currently indicate in your question. Please edit your question to include the full text of the error message you're getting **verbatim**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Order__c ord = new Order__c(Account_Name__c=acct.Id, Delegate_Admin__c=cont.LastName, 
        Number_of_Users__c=5,  CurrencyIsoCode='EUR - Euro',Order_Amount__c=1500,
        Opportunity_Name__c=Opp.Name);
```

It looks like `Delegate_Admin__c` is a lookup field (type Id), but you assigned the LastName field from the contact to this field. It should probably instead be `Delegate_Admin__c=cont.Id`. The same is probably also true for `Opportunity_Name__c=Opp.Name`, but it should probably be `Opportunity_Name__c=opp.Id`.

In the future, I strongly suggest you avoid naming lookup fields with the word "name", because that suggests that it is not an Id field. This is probably the source of your confusion.

Comment: @sfdfox I tried your suggestions but still get :USER_DEBUG [16]|DEBUG|assigning pricebook id null to opportunity

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line

```
 Id     value6 = o.Opportunity_Name__c;
```

into

```
 string     value6 = o.Opportunity_Name__c;
```

You are assigning string value into Id. Thats why you are getting this error. You need to use string variable here.

Comment: I tried that but have the same error

Comment: @Jenssen Try for `string value7 = o.Product__c;` as well. As we are not sure if thats a lookup field or text field.

Comment: Tried that also but no relief: USER_DEBUG [16]|DEBUG|assigning pricebook id null to opportunity

Comment: @Jenssen are you getting same original error message? Also what are you getting here `system.debug('opp.Pricebook2Id '+opp.Pricebook2Id);`

Comment: @Jenssen why did you downvoted the asnwer?

Comment: I didnt! downvoted the answer see: USER_DEBUG [33]|DEBUG|opp.Pricebook2Id 01s4E0000009yEsQAI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66938/discussion-between-tushar-sharma-and-jenssen).